# Showing that $f$ is continuous given some conditions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ and function. Suppose that $X=\cup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ and each restriction of $f$ to $A_n$ is continuous where we regard $A_n$ as the subspace topology.
Show that

(i) If $A_n$ is open in $X$ for each $n\ge 1$ then $f$ is continuous.

(ii) If $A_n\subset$ Int$(A_{n+1})$ for all $n\ge 1$ then $f$ is continuous.

I have done part (i). I tried to proceed accordingly in part (ii) but to no avail. Can anyone suggest a ***hint*** for (ii)?

Comment: Replace $A_n$ with their interior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_n=\text{Int}(A_n)$ are open. What is the union of the $B_n$?